# Как, зная 7 фамилий, найти знакомых в социальной сети?

Tags: vkontakte-api, поиск, facebook-api, соцсети

У меня вопрос по поиску людей в социальной сети.

---

**УСЛОВИЯ**

Пусть я знаю несколько человек (знаю их фамилии), например 7 человек. Предполагаю, что эти люди как-то связаны между собой в социальной сети, например они друзья, или просто переписываются.

---

**ВОПРОС**

В какую графу в социальной сети мне ввести эти 7 фамилий, чтобы после запуска поиска получить необходимый мне результат?

---

**ЧТО Я ХОЧУ УВИДЕТЬ В РЕЗУЛЬТАТАХ ПОИСКА**

1. Перечень групп из людей.
2. В каждой группе 7 или менее человек.
3. Перечень групп отсортировать по вероятности нахождения необходимого результата.

---

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ**

Если такого поиска нет в самой этой социальной сети, то что вы посоветуете?
Сторонние сервисы в интернете, или скрипты, или API, или другое?

Comment: Вряд ли на сайте социальной сети будет возможность для такого необычного запроса. Попробуйте воспользоваться официальным API, но и тут, не исключено, не будет возможности для анализа.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию и теме сайта.